# change html form value, load page & click button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get user input via an html form, update that input via javacript , load a webpage where i will use the updated input to load in.  Everything is going well except i can't seem to get that webpages button to click and actually log in with the inputted fields.

EDIT::  To be clear , this page will have a button for user name input.  the user inputs his name and clicks the button.  I then update that user input and load a new webpage where i will fill a username field and click a button "login".

I have everything working, but i can't seem to click that "login" button on the second webpage.  Looking at the webpage i know the class type name and value of the button i need to click

class="btn" type="submit" name="action" value="login"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function func()
{

 var str1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
 var str2 = "12345";
 document.getElementById("name").value = str1.concat(str2);
 return true;

  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="website.com" method="POST">
<input name="login" id="name" value="username" />
<button id="button" onclick="func()">press button</button>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MilanChheda both will work

Comment: Give type="button" in button tag

Comment: @Vineesh - Ok..

Comment: this clicks the first button, but not the second

Answer (score 3):

try it

```js
function func() {
  var str1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var str2 = "12345";
  document.getElementById("name").value = str1.concat(str2);
  return true;


}
```

```html
<form action="website.com" method="POST">
  <input name="login" id="name" value="username" />
  <button id="button" onclick="func()">press button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think this is the code i already had.  This will get everything to work except it will not click the button on the second page

Comment: what do you mean by second page one button define in one page how it will use one second page...? @razeal113

Comment: I made an edit to my original question to hopefully make this a bit clearer.  The code i wrote will have a username field and a button to click.  Once the user clicks that button, i update his inputted data , load a new webpage, fill a login field with the updated value and click a button.  But i cannot seem to click that second button .

I know the class, type, name, value of this second button but just need a way to click it

Comment: Well thats the part im not sure how to write.  This should load website.com and send the updated user input from the JS , load it into the username field and click a login button.

The username field gets filled with the correct data, but i cant click the button.  So i just need a way for JS (or anyway) to click a button once a webpage is loaded and filled with data